# When using ElasticsearchRepository, how to get delete response status?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring-Data-Elasticsearch in my project, and I want to delete document by ElasticsearchRepository interface.

There is not a response from `delete` api, so I can't distinguish whether the document existed in ES.

I don't want to seperate into two steps by using `exists()` api.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

As you known there is nothing returned by the `delete` method so you have to use `boolean existsById(ID primaryKey);` first to know if it exists.

Elasticsearch is a very fast engine, so the cost is nothing, except if you want to delete a million documents.